# Running javascript in Chrome console runs twice sometimes, why?

Tags: javascript, html

this code takes some values from a page, compares them and presses a button if true, and it does that in a loop

Running this pice of javascript in chrome console works fine for some time and then it runs two time. The script works fine with a compiler so why does it sometimes do that in Chrome console? And is there a way to execute the code just once all the time, without taking out `setInterval` or `setTimeout` or if, as I absolutely need them!

```js
setInterval(function() {
        var time = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;;
        if(time>0){
        
       setTimeout(function() {
               
            var x2b = document.getElementById("2x").innerHTML;
            var x3b = document.getElementById("3x").innerHTML;
            
            
            var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            
            if (x3b< x2b) {
                    
                    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                    var run = document.getElementById("3x");
                    run.dispatchEvent(evt);}
                    
                    
            
        }, time);}

    }, 2000);
```

Comment: How could `time` ever be below zero when it never gets modified?

Comment: well not sure how you expect it not to run multiple times when you call it on a loop that never stops.....

Answer (score 0):

Probably a problem with your code and not Chrome.

How does `#timer` get updated? If it's value happens to be something like `2500` then the `setTimeout` will be placed on the call stack. Then 2000ms later the next interval will occur. If `#timer` happens to be something like `500` at that time then another `setTimeout` will be placed on the call stack. After another 500ms both of the timeouts will be triggered, one right after another. This may make it appear that the timeout is occurring twice.

It would be helpful to record the current time (`Date.now()`) and what the value of `#timer` is, and log that info when the timeout occurs.